# Subscript of math operator not appearing properly in fraction

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts

Here is the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \lambda=\frac{\operatornamewithlimits{\max}_{\theta \in \Omega_0}L(\theta)}{\operatornamewithlimits{\max}_{\theta \in \Omega}L(\theta)}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: fraction with subscript after max]

The subscript appears in the fraction after "max" instead of below "max". I've tried to put the expression with the subscript outside the fraction and the subscript appears bellow "max".
Why does that happens?
How can I get this:

[image: fraction with subscript bellow max]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this by putting `\limits` after `\max` and dropping the `\operatornamewithlimits`. But you really shouldn't. This is done on purpose so that your fractions don't get too large, and, imho, the result with `\limits` looks weird.

Nevertheless, this is how you could get it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \lambda=\frac{\max\limits_{\theta \in \Omega_0}L(\theta)}{\max\limits_{\theta \in \Omega}L(\theta)}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice!